# Creating multiple form elements in html table to update SQL table

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm using a SELECT query to generate a html table (screenshot) which displays data from a sql table.

Every `<tr>` is generating an additional `<tr>` for the administrator (`if` `($userUid == "admin") {`)  with the sql entry's `ID` + `<textarea>` to edit the content in the SQL column `public`.

The second administrator `<tr>` includes a `<form>` element to edit the content. I assume the repeating `name` elements of the multiple `<input>s / <button>s` in the form element cause the problem, but the script `action="includes/update.inc.php"` just returns a blank page with the following URL and no php error:

```
http://localhost:10006/includes/update.inc.php?editId=18&editContent=adsasd&submit-edit=
```

Generated table:

```
<?php
<table> ... / table head...

foreach($result as $row) {

echo "<tr class='data-row'>";
  echo "<td>".$date_form."</td>
  echo "<td>".$time_form."</td>
  echo "<td>".$subject_form."</td>
  echo "<td>".$private."</td>
  echo "<td>".$public."</td>
  echo "<td>".$date_form."</td>
echo "</tr>";

if ($userUid == "admin") { ?>

<tr class='admin-row'>
  <form action="includes/update.inc.php" type="post">
    <td><input name="editId" type="text" value="<?php echo $Id; ?>"></td>
    <td class='p-2' colspan="4">
      <textarea name="editContent" class="content-update-textarea" type="text"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td><button name="submit-edit" type="submit">EDIT</button></td>
  </form>
</tr>

 <?php }}?>
</table>
```

This is the /includes/update.inc.php script called by the form element which is supposed to update the content using `<textarea name="editContent">` of the SQL row with the ID: `<input name='editId'>`.

```
<?php
  include 'dbh.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit-edit'])) {

  $id = $_POST['editId'];
  $editContent = $_POST['editContent'];


  $sql = "UPDATE lesson SET public = ? WHERE id = ?";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "Failed to prepare statement.";
    exit();
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $editContent, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header ("Location: ../lesson.php?update=success");
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change form's attribute "type" to "method".
Your code after:  `<form action="includes/update.inc.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

First, you make sure that your value is correctly transported into the backend section.

```
<?php
  include 'dbh.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit-edit'])) {

  $id = $_POST['editId'];
  $editContent = $_POST['editContent']; echo $editContent; //Verification step

  /*$sql = "UPDATE lesson SET public = ? WHERE id = ?";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "Failed to prepare statement.";
    exit();
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $editContent, $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    header ("Location: ../lesson.php?update=success");
  }*/
}
```